# SAS: Reading in CSV file in Sas: Character date getting 0 added

Tags: csv, date, sas

My CSV file has a date column, some rows are like DDMMMYY other rows are like DMMMYY (for example 2-Oct-19).
When I read in DMMMYY it comes out as DDMMMYY. So 2-Oct-19 becomes 02-Oct-19.
How can I keep it as DMMMYY (2-Oct-19)?

I am using code like this:

```
data ds;
  infile "file.csv"
  delimiter=',' missover dsd lrecl=32767 firstobs=3;
  informat datevar $20.
  format datevar $20.;
  input datevar $;
run;
```

Comment: How are you opening the CSV to confirm it has no leading zero?

Comment: Hi Joe,With excel

Comment: Then you're probably seeing Excel hiding the leading zero.  Open the CSV with Notepad/etc., you probably see a leading zero!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your CSV already has the leading zero, and Excel is just hiding it for you with its default date/time formats.  The best choice in SAS is usually to read in as a *numeric* and then format it however you wish:

```
data ds;
  infile "file.csv"
  delimiter=',' missover dsd lrecl=32767 firstobs=3;
  informat datevar date9.;
  format datevar date9.;
  input datevar;
run;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your CSV file:

```
id,datevar
1,2-Oct-2019
2,10-Jun-2020
3,1-May-2018
```

You can use custom SAS formats (see **Derek P. Morgan/The Essential Guide to SAS® Dates and Times, Second Edition**, SAS Press, page 50):

```
PROC FORMAT;
     PICTURE ZWDATE
              . - .z = "No Date Given"
              LOW - HIGH = '%d-%b-%Y' (DATATYPE=DATE);
```

RUN;

SAS code:

```
data ds;
   infile "file.csv"
   delimiter=',' missover dsd lrecl=32767 firstobs=2;
   input id datevar : $11.;
   datevarn=input(datevar,date11.);
   format datevarn ZWDATE.;
run;

proc print data=ds noobs;run;
```

Output:

[image]